# Angular - Capture results of a compiled view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a form that's compiled on screen a nicely laid out format. I need to take what's on screen (the HTML) and post it to the server to be emailed out. I'm trying to avoid doing double the work and redesigning it in my .NET codebehind. Is there a way to capture what's on screen within a certain div? I've tried jQuery $('#div').html() and vanilla JS and no luck.

This is what I'm trying to grab, not overly complex but the areas that are blacked out are all generated by my controller and regular ng-models, ng-binds and ng-repeat.

I just need the HTML and I can handle the rest from there. Thanks!

[image: Sample of what I'm trying to grab]

**UPDATE**
Here's the working version of the code the $('.output').html() grabs the content in the container I need inside the Angular $timeout function. This is then posted to an API that handles the actual delivery and formatting of the email.

```
$timeout(function () {
            var reviewPost = {
                OrderNumber: $('#hidOrderNumber').val(),
                PostedContent: '<h3>Customer PO: ' + $scope.orderInfo.MOR_Title + '</h3><h3>Website Order #: ' + $('#hidOrderNumber').val() + ' - Assigned for website processing</h3>' + $('.output').html()
            };

            $http.post('/api/order/emailOrder', reviewPost).then(function (results) {
                if (results.status === 200) {
                    $scope.$parent.showSimpleToast("Email Sent");
                } else {
                    $scope.$parent.showSimpleToast("An Error Occurred. Please contact technical support.", 20000);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by no luck? What is the ouput of the html from jQuery? Have you tried using $timeout as the page may not have been compiled?

Comment: I didn't even think of using $timeout. The gap between when I was populating the info and when I was trying to grab it seemed be long enough. It was grabbing all the uncompiled code, none of my data in there.

Comment: Can I see your code as to where you are trying to grab the html? As you mentioned, it was grabbing the template code so it would seem that the template has not compiled at that point.